# How to type scroll event in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, event-handling, uievent

Tell me how to correctly type the scrollHandler function in this case.

`

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('submit', scrollHandler);

  return () => document.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
})

const scrollHandler = (e: React.UIEvent<??>) => {
  console.log(e)
}
```

`
Code example on [CodeSandBox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-types-lw6re2)

I have tried React.UIEvent React.UIEvent and etc. but it doesn't work, it throws an error :(

Thanks in advance to everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

const scrollHandler = (e: Event) => { console.log(e) }